# Checking processes which hold a file in Linux & Windows

Tags: windows, linux, io

Is there any command which can check any processes holding a file in Linux and in Windows ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) and [`fuser`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)) can be used on Linux (and other Unix-like systems).

For Windows, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can be used for that, or [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) for a command-line version.

Comment: Hi Mat, Thanks... That's very helpful. Btw, no command line alternative for Process Explorer ?